# How to get more disk space on Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I'm using Cloud Shell to deploy an application to GKE, and I've run out of disk space during the build:

```
overlay          31G   31G   44M 100% /
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /dev
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        31G   31G   44M 100% /root
/dev/sdb1       4.8G   85M  4.5G   2% /home
tmpfs           848M  716K  847M   1% /run/metrics
overlayfs       1.0M  116K  908K  12% /etc/ssh/keys
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
overlayfs       1.0M  116K  908K  12% /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /run/google/devshell
```

...AIUI, /dev/sda1 is the underlying VM's disk, and it seems to be 31G. And it's full, which is causing `skaffold run` to fail. Can I (temporarily|permanently) get more space on that disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no way to temporarily or permanently get more Cloud Shell disk space on the boot disk, but we have recently bumped everyone's disk size by 5G to give a bit more headroom.  Check back in a few days when this change fully rolls out.  We are also looking into optimizing the size of the default Cloud Shell image to reduce its footprint on the VM.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the details. FWIW, an extra 5GB is great, but I doubt it'll be enough for my use case, so I'd still like the option to add lots of GB (for a price). My hope is to use the Cloud Shell as my "local developer" machine. But that means I need moar disk.

Answer (score 0):

One trick to make use of a bit of extra space: your persistent `$HOME` directory has a separate 5 GB allocation in addition to the 32 GB on the local filesystem.

You'll also want to make sure any output is sent `$HOME`, because otherwise it will not be persisted when the hosting VM is recycled.